# How am I only swapping one as opposed to two values?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, swap

I am working on an exercise in which I have to code a 'tile' game. This function is supposed to find a blank tile within a multi-dimensional array. The user then selects a tile by passing in an integer known as 'tile'. If the 'tile' that the user inputs is adjacent to the blank tile, then they need to swap

Right now however, this is not happening. I have been told that "the problem is that you're swapping the value of a single item in board with the variable tile. The variable tile may *have* the same value as an item in the board, but it *isn't* the item in the board. You need to swap two items on the board."

Also, apparently: "But the second part of my `if` statement only checks to see that tile isn't behind the lowest right corner of the board. Wouldn't you be more interested to know if `blankCol - 1` is less than zero?

'd' is the size of the board that the user previously chose at the start of the program. If they chose 3, d = 3 and thus the multi-dimensional array would equal 3x3 (d * d).
Yet I cannot, for the life of me work out what this means:

```
bool move(int tile)
{
    int temp;
    int didSwap;
    int blankRow;
    int blankCol;

    // search for blank tile

    for (int row = 0; row < d; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < d; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] == 0) {
                blankRow = row;
                blankCol = col;
            }
        }
    }

    // check that tile is not too big or too small

    if (tile > d * d - 1 || tile < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // search for blank tile

    for (int row = 0; row < d; row++) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < d; col++) {
            if (tile == board[blankRow + 1][blankCol] &&
                tile != board[d + 1][d]) {
                temp = board[blankRow][blankCol];
                board[blankRow][blankCol] = tile;
                tile = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
                return true;
            }
            else if (tile == board[blankRow - 1][blankCol] &&
                     tile != board[d - 1][d]) {
                temp = board[blankRow][blankCol];
                board[blankRow][blankCol] = tile;
                tile = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
                return true;
            }
            else if (tile == board[blankRow][blankCol + 1] &&
                     tile != board[d][d + 1]) {
                temp = board[blankRow][blankCol];
                board[blankRow][blankCol] = tile;
                tile = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
                return true;
            }
            else if (tile == board[blankRow][blankCol - 1] &&
                     tile != board[d][d + 1]) {
                temp = board[blankRow][blankCol];
                board[blankRow][blankCol] = tile;
                tile = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you please make some suggestions as to where I should go from here?

Thank you

Comment: What is `d`? It appears to be the dimension of the board, but then you use `board[d+1][d]`. Also note that if you don't find a blank tile, `blankRow` and `blankCol` will be uninitialised.

Comment: A quick look at your code reveals a lot of repetition. You MUST stick to the DRY principle. Because if there's a bug now somewhere you also have multiple copies of the bug. Maintaining such code is wey harder than searching for the code that normalizes this and prevents repetition/duplication of code completely.

Comment: In real life terms, your code is equivalent to this. You are holding a 15 puzzle, there's an `8` tile next to the blank space, someone passes you a tile with an `8` on it, and you put that tile in the blank space. Now your board has two `8` tiles and no blank space. What do you do next?

Comment: So I haven't put the blank space into where the 8 tile previous was? I think

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the problem is that you are only setting the value of one board tile: exactly one `board[(row)][(col)] = (value)` statement is executed in your function.

For example:

```
       if (tile == board[blankRow + 1][blankCol] &&
            tile != board[d + 1][d]) {
            temp = board[blankRow][blankCol];
            board[blankRow][blankCol] = tile;
            tile = temp;
            didSwap = 1;
            return true;
        }
```

Notice that there is only one `board[...][...] =` - type statement? So it's only setting one tile value on the board.

The `tile = temp;` statement, which you seem to believe should change the first tile and thus complete the swap operation, is just assigning to a local variable. It's not changing the value recorded in the `board` array.

I believe there are other issues in your code however. You have two comments saying "search for the blank tile", but clearly the first comment is correct and the second was copy-pasted but is now inaccurate: the code is instead search for the tile to move. However, searching the whole board for a tile which must be next to a particular tile is (at best) inefficient. Why not search just the squares immediately around the blank tile? You also need to make sure you do not go out of array bounds, consider:

```
        else if (tile == board[blankRow - 1][blankCol] &&
                 tile != board[d - 1][d]) {
```

... what if `blankRow` is 0? - then you are accessing `board[-1][blankCol]` which will invoke undefined behaviour and may cause your program to fail or exhibit strange behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Too many issues :

1. Assume `d=5`, Check tile out of range, user enters `25`, it will show out of range.

change code to :

```
if Tile>d*d
```

2. Try the following steps also :

   1. Find blank tile
   2. See if the user entered an adjacent tile. No loops required for this, only `4` If stmta for up, down, left right.
   3. if indeed adjacent, then swap values.